# Understanding the flow of adding facebook login to iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-login, facebook-ios-sdk

I am trying desperately to integrate facebook login with my app, with no success so far.

1. I have installed the needed pods as instructed in firebase and facebook websites.
2. Followed the tutorial provided by firebase.
3. I think I have added the needed code to both the AppDelegate class and LoginViewController. (I am of course adding the code of both classes) :
4. I have read some stuff about login manager and permissions but none of these is mentioned in both facebook and firebase tutorials.

I can't seem to figure out the flow of this process. the delegate method doesn't lunch when I press the FBLoginButton (added print statement to check).

I am using Swift 5 and not so good with objective-c so swift code suggestions would be fantastic.

Thanks a lot in advance!

```
//
//  LogInViewController.swift
//  Flash Chat
//
//  This is the view controller where users login
// Control–Command–Space bar to get emojes

import UIKit
import Firebase
import SVProgressHUD
import GoogleSignIn
import FirebaseUI
import FBSDKLoginKit
import FBSDKCoreKit

class LogInViewController: UIViewController, GIDSignInUIDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate, LoginButtonDelegate {


    //Textfields pre-linked with IBOutlets
    @IBOutlet var emailTextfield: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var passwordTextfield: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var fbLoginButton: FBLoginButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var upperView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var warningLabel: UILabel!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        addGesture()
        initGIDSignIn()
        initFBSignIn()
    }

    private func addGesture () {
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: view, action: #selector(UIView.endEditing))
        upperView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    }

    private func roundCorners(button: UIButton) {
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        button.layer.borderWidth = 1
        button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    //MARK: Google Sign In

    private func initGIDSignIn () {
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID
    }

    @IBAction func signInViaGooglePressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.signIn()
    }

    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error?) {
        if error != nil {
            print("Error")
            return
        }
        guard let authentication = user.authentication else { return }
        let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: authentication.idToken,
                                                       accessToken: authentication.accessToken)
        Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (authResult, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("Error")
                return
            }
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToChat", sender: self)
        }

    }

    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!,present viewController: UIViewController!) {
        self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!,dismiss viewController: UIViewController!) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    //MARK: Facebook Sign In

    private func initFBSignIn () {
        fbLoginButton = FBLoginButton()
        fbLoginButton.delegate = self
    }

    func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBLoginButton, didCompleteWith result: LoginManagerLoginResult?, error: Error?) {
        print("Got to this place")
        if error != nil {
            print("Error")
            return
        }

        let credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: AccessToken.current!.tokenString)
        Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (authResult, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("Error!")
                return
            }
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToChat", sender: self)
        }
    }

    func loginButtonDidLogOut(_ loginButton: FBLoginButton) {
        print("logged out")
    }

    // MARK: Regular Login

    @IBAction func logInPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        SVProgressHUD.show()
        if checkDetailsValidity(){
            Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: emailTextfield.text!, password: passwordTextfield.text!) { (user, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    self.warningLabel.text = "Incorrect email or password"
                    SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                }
                else {
                    SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                    print("Successfuly logged in!")
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToChat", sender: self)
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
        }
    }

    private func checkDetailsValidity() -> Bool {
        if emailTextfield.text!.isEmpty {
            warningLabel.text = "Email is mandatory field"
            return false
        }
        else if !emailTextfield.text!.contains("@") || !emailTextfield.text!.contains("."){
            warningLabel.text = "Email is illegal"
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import GoogleSignIn
import FBSDKCoreKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }



    @available(iOS 9.0, *)
    func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool {
        if (GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url,
                                             sourceApplication: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,
                                             annotation: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.annotation]))
        {
            return true;

        }else if(url.absoluteString.contains("www.mydomain.com")){
            print("incoming url \(url.absoluteString)")

            return true
        }
        else if ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(app, open: url, sourceApplication: options[.sourceApplication] as? String, annotation: options[.annotation]) {
                return true

        }

        return false
    }

//    // [START openurl]
//    @available(iOS 8.0, *)
//    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
//                     open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
//
//
//        if (GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url,
//                                              sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
//                                              annotation: annotation))
//        {
//            return true;
//        }else if(url.absoluteString.contains("www.mydomain.com")){
//
//            print("incoming url \(url.absoluteString)")
//            return true
//        }
//
//        return false;
//
//    }






}
```

Comment: Are you wanting to simply authenticate with an existing Facebook app? That's another important question, have you registered an app through developers.facebook.com? I assume you have.

Comment: Your AppDelegate isn't correct.

Comment: I want people to be able to connect to my app using their Facebook account. I have done it with google and it worked. And yes, I have registered my app.

Answer (score -1):

Within `application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?)`, be sure to add the following code:

```
FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance()?.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
```

It seems that you were simply calling...

```
ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
```

...and confusing the two. Try this out and let me know if it helps.

Comment: Xcode keeps telling me the FBSDKApplicationDelegate has been renamed to ApplicationDeligate so I let it fix it..